# UITEXTVIEW: Get the recent word typed in uitextview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview, uimenucontroller

I want to get the most recent word entered by the user from the UITextView.

The user can enter a word anywhere in the UITextView, in the middle or in the end or in the beginning. I would consider it a word when the user finishes typing it and presses a space and does any corrections using the "Suggestions from the `UIMenuController`".

Example: User types in "kimd" in the `UITextView` somewhere in the middle of text, he gets a popup for autocorrection "kind" which he does. After he does that, I want to capture "kind" and use it in my application.

I searched a lot on the internet but found solutions that talk about when the user enters text in the end. I also tried detecting a space and then doing a backward search until another space after some text is found, so that i can qualify it as a word. But I think there may be better ways to do this.

I have read somewhere that iOS caches the recent text that we enter in a text field or text view. If I can pop off the top one , that's all I want. I just need handle to that object.

I would really appreciate the help.

Note: The user can enter text anywhere in UItextview. I need the most recent entered word

Thanks.

Comment: Note: The user can enter text anywhere in UItextview. I need the most recent entered word

Comment: Isn't there a way to get the cached strings in iOS. This way we can just say "object.getTheLastCachedString" or something like that. There is a class called NSCache, that helps us cache data to it but for this particular situation it may not be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//This method looks for the recent string entered by user and then takes appropriate action.

     - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

 //Look for Space or any specific string such as a space
if ([text isEqualToString:@" "]) {
NSMutableCharacterSet *workingSet = [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]   mutableCopy];

  NSRange newRange = [self.myTextView.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:workingSet
                                     options:NSBackwardsSearch
                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, (currentLocation - 1))];

 //The below code could be done in a better way...
 UITextPosition *beginning = myTextView.beginningOfDocument;
 UITextPosition *start = [myTextView positionFromPosition:beginning offset:currentLocation];
 UITextPosition *end = [myTextView positionFromPosition:beginning   offset:newRangeLocation+1];
 UITextRange *textRange = [myTextView textRangeFromPosition:end toPosition:start];

 NSString* str = [self.myTextView textInRange:textRange]; 
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the variable currentLocation coming from?

Comment: @RobCaraway ```range.location```

Comment: newRangeLocation ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would suggest doing, might seem a little hacky but it would work just fine:

First in .h conform to the `UITextViewDelegate` and set your text view's `delegate` to `self` like this:

```
myTextView.delegate = self;
```

and use this code:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView { // Delegate method called when any text is modified

if ([textView.text substringFromIndex: [textView.text length] - 1]) { // Gets last character of the text view's text

    NSArray *allWords = [[textView text] componentsSeparatedByString: @" "]; // Gets the text view's text and fills an array with all strings seperated by a space in text view's text, basically all the words

    NSString *mostRecentWord = [allWords lastObject]; // The most recent word!
}

}
```

Comment: Getting the last object in allWords  will not work for me because it will always get the last word entered in the text view which is not necessary the most recent word.

I want the most recent word entered by the user. The user may enter it anywhere, in the beginning middle or end of the text view.

Comment: @MCKapur NP. I will post if I find a solution.

Comment: @NoorSyed Ok, Im interested in finding this too

Comment: @NoorSyed Did you eventually find a solution?

Comment: Yes I did. Will be posting it.

Comment: @MCKapur NP. I have posted my solution.Comments?

Comment: @MCKapur read the question properly first. The question specifically mentioned that, text can be edited from any position inside the UITextView

Answer (score 1):

I use this code to get the word behind the @-sign:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSRange rangeOfLastInsertedCharacter = textView.selectedRange;
    rangeOfLastInsertedCharacter.location = MAX(rangeOfLastInsertedCharacter.location - 1,0);
    rangeOfLastInsertedCharacter.length = 1;
    NSString *lastInsertedSubstring;
    NSString *mentionSubString;
    if (![textView.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        lastInsertedSubstring = [textView.text substringWithRange:rangeOfLastInsertedCharacter];
        if (self.startOfMention > 0 || self.startOfHashtag > 0) {
            if ([lastInsertedSubstring isEqualToString:@" "] || (self.startOfMention > textView.selectedRange.location || self.startOfHashtag > textView.selectedRange.location)) {
                self.startOfMention = 0;
                self.lenthOfMentionSubstring = 0;
            }
        }
        if (self.startOfMention > 0) {
            self.lenthOfMentionSubstring = textView.selectedRange.location - self.startOfMention;
            NSRange rangeOfMentionSubstring = {self.startOfMention, textView.selectedRange.location - self.startOfMention};
            mentionSubString = [textView.text substringWithRange:rangeOfMentionSubstring];
            dhDebug(@"mentionSubString: %@", mentionSubString);

            UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, nil);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have to try with your solution. Isn't there a way to get the cached strings in iOS. This way we can just say "object.getTheLastCachedString" or something like that.

Comment: I only know this solution.

Comment: where `self.startOfMention`, `self.lenthOfMentionSubstring` these are going to be assigned

Answer (score 1):

Simple extension for `UITextView`:

```
extension UITextView {

    func editedWord() -> String {

        let cursorPosition = selectedRange.location
        let separationCharacters = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: " ")

        let beginRange = Range(start: text.startIndex.advancedBy(0), end: text.startIndex.advancedBy(cursorPosition))
        let endRange = Range(start: text.startIndex.advancedBy(cursorPosition), end: text.startIndex.advancedBy(text.characters.count))

        let beginPhrase = text.substringWithRange(beginRange)
        let endPhrase = text.substringWithRange(endRange)

        let beginWords = beginPhrase.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(separationCharacters)
        let endWords = endPhrase.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(separationCharacters)

        return beginWords.last! + endWords.first!
    }
}
```